# serviceNotAvailable - Microsoft Graph

Tags: php, microsoft-graph-api

A webapp i have been developing in PHP suddenly started returning the following error from Microsoft Graph when trying to log in via Microsoft.
It worked fine a month ago and i haven't really touched it since.

```
{
    "error": {
      "code": "serviceNotAvailable",
      "message": "The server is unable to process the current request.",
      "innerError": {
        "request-id": "37804663-4a21-4ca1-8ddf-e12cd5765d00",
        "date": "2022-11-21T10:54:25"
      }
    }
  }
```

I have double checked that the scope of app permisions are correct and that there are no conflicts.
API keys are also valid and not expired.

I have the following app permisions:
User.Read (Delegated)
offline_access (Delegated)
openid (Delegated)
profile (Delegated)

Comment: Could you please help me to understand what you have tried , which call give you the error "serviceNotAvailable", thanks

Comment: Sorry for not being specific enough, oauth2 part works. Tested this yesterday so the problem isn't related to login, it's when i for instance try to get my own profile from the Graph api. Any call i make towards the graph api returns this error.

Comment: Thanks for the update , as you said any call towards graph api , returns the error ? have you tried this in graph explorer - https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer ? please try to call - https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me , and please add the timestamp and request id for the call, thanks

Comment: Same result with the graph explorer. Can some kind of security policy in the tenant block these requests?  I have limited understanding of the microsoft ecosystem but code is one thing i do understand. Is the security policy even a thing? Or are there some other tenant based rules that could interfere with the graph api calling?

Comment: Provide us the Fiddler or the time stamp and the request id, its hard to say what's going wrong there ,  Can you try the code on the test tenant?